# Why i am getting error "page not found" after after making the url dynamic in django

Tags: django, url, dynamic

Why am I getting this error..
"page not found" while trying to implement dynamic url in Django. Please see my code and advice me. It works fine when url is not dynamic, but as soon as the url is made dynamic it shows the error.

**view**:

```
def detail_post(request,my_id):
    return render(request, 'dynamic/showdetail.html')
```

**urls**:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('detail/<my_id>/', views.detail_post, name="detail")
]
```

Comment: def detail_post(request,my_id):
    return render(request, 'dynamic/showdetail.html')... here is my view

Comment: What url do you make the request to (what url do you type in your browser)?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/  ... i type this and the result is "page not found"

Comment: Your url pattern expects an argument after detail... So instead of `127.0.0.1:8000/detail/` it would be something along the lines of `127.0.0.1:8000/detail/something-here/`

Comment: Thanks a lot.....it works ... I am new one. here. from a different educational background....and this error was lowering my enthusiasm ...thanks again. i was trying hard whole day..but no youtube video suggested anything good...